# Why getting this error transformClassesWithDexForDebug while building apk?

Tags: android

While building apk I am getting this error:
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p5Py.png)

This is my gradle Image: [gradle image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO3Q7.png)

**Note:- I started getting this error after including android-support-v4.jar to project**

If anyone know this so please tell me why I am getting this error and how to solve It.

Comment: Please put your code in text not a screenshot.  This is because it's not convenient if someone wants to run it.  Second it can't be easily seen on some devices.

Answer (score 0):

Your last line has a dependency of support-v4 using a jar file in your lib folder that you might have placed.

Either remove the file and the last line or remove the support-v4 dependency that you have highlighted.

Add the following to your project level build.gradle file if not already present

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Add the support-v4 dependency as follows to your app level build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
```

Remove the following along with the jar file:

```
compile files('libs/support-v4.jar')
```

Now your gradle will use the dependency and download the aar on it's own from the maven repository and not use the jar file that you have added.

Comment: If i remove file then how I can i use that lib

Comment: You have added a compile support-v4 line, that's tell gradle to download the aar and use it. You can't have both a jar file in libs folder and that file as they both add the same dependency

Comment: but when I am removing jar from lib folder It giving me file not found exception while building apk

Comment: steps to follow if they need further clarification https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html

Comment: If it worked, please do accept the answer so that others don't spend time answering this again